# RavenDB - DefaultContractResolver trying to call RegisterForExtensionData when the data setter is already set

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ravendb

*Hi everyone*

I'm trying to setup a small MVC web application project using Ninject for Ioc container and RavenDB for Database.

In the project, there is an "Alert" AR which is depending on a clock service and the clock service is depending on "TheClientPreference", both Alert and TheClientPreference are saved in Database.

The probelm I'm currently facing is whenever I try to deserialize "Alert" from Database, it also needs to resolve the clock service via dependency injection which then require the application to deserialize "TheClientPreference" at the same time, and this is where it causes the error of "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot add a data setter because on is already added".

Instead of pre-loading "TheClientPreference" as constant value and use Ioc container to bind it as singleton at application startup, is there any other ways to solve this issue?

**Partial Stack Trace:**

[InvalidOperationException: Cannot add a data setter because on is already added]
   Raven.Client.Document.DefaultRavenContractResolver.RegisterForExtensionData(ExtensionDataSetter setter) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DefaultRavenContractResolver.cs:40
   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity(Type entityType, String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:509

**Project Reference**

I have also created a public repository to demonstrate/re-produce the error for your reference, which can be found at the following:
https://github.com/andyinaus/MyTestDemo

Any answer/help is much appreciated.